# Why does Xenial/16.04 not ship sntp?

Tags: 16.04, ntp

I can find sntp for trusty on systemd.

I need to run a cron job that calls `sntp -s server1 server2`.

What can do the same thing for me on 16.04?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is an outstanding bug. See https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ntp/+bug/1604010 for potential work arounds.

The bug report is marked as resolved in "upstream", debian in this case.

https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=793837

but has not been resolved in Ubuntu at the time of this question.

Comment: Is there an additional installable package which will use `adjtime(3)` to monotonically adjust the clock to NTP servers?

Comment: The bug report I linked has 2 or 3 options for work around or you could recompile the package, again directions in bug report for which flag to enable.